# java ee server similar to cassini

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I primarily use Tomcat and Glassfish for Java EE development at work, but was wondering if anyone knew of any small application servers like [Cassini](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/) for ASP.NET that would make building and testing faster? I would still eventually deploy to one of our production tomcat/glassfish servers, but would prefer something that is simpler and quicker.

I am probably going to take [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) and [geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) for a spin, any others I should check out?

Comment: What part of building and testing do you want to make faster?  Where do you think you are wasting time in your current workflow?  There are some very simple strategies for improving your workflow with GF.  For some reason they do not get a lot of 'play'...  The easiest change that you can make to your workflow is to stop using the jar command... Both TC and GF support directory deployment.  Use it and be faster... with the tools that you already use.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing now. I've been using Cassini for local development and testing and it is much faster and has less features than IIS. I typically use TC for development and just do full directory deployments. I'm just looking for other solutions. If you have any advice on streamlining the development cycle using TC or GF I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

jetty is good for testing, because it's very easy to start a jetty instance in your tests. if you're also concerned about faster development, then the choice of server is not the only factor.

there's also [jonas](http://wiki.jonas.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) and [resin](http://www.caucho.com/)

Comment: I will add these to my list to check out.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) which eliminates the need to do a redeploy on ~80% of the cases, making the development quicker.

Comment: that looks great, but I couldn't bring myself to spend money on it.

Comment: There's a 30 day test with no cost and you can get it for free if you are a contributor to an open source project

Answer (score 1):

*This may not answer your question directly, but you may want to consider alternative Framework/Server combinations.*

Here are a few Java RAD stacks that I have used in the past and work very well when trying to achieve a rapid development -> build -> test loop:

- [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo)
- [Grails](http://grails.org/)
- [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)

Granted, these are not application servers in their own right, but each of them are frameworks/servers that can be used to achieve the results you are looking for.  Roo and Play are both Java based, and Grails is Groovy based.

None of these solutions will work if you are looking for a plain container to deploy your application in to.  These are more like all in one solutions.

Comment: Good point. I have been wanting to do some Grails stuff for a while. Although, for right now, these solutions wouldn't work for me as I do need to deploy to a regular container at some point.

Comment: Both Roo and Grails produce AFAIK war files you can deploy on any regular container
Play looks great for creating a RESTful-based application, and it is a strong competitor to Jersey on that regard, I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

> (...) but was wondering if anyone knew of any small application servers like Cassini for ASP.NET that would make building and testing faster?

You should have a look at this [Short screencast on GlassFish v3 session redeployment](http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/short_screencast_on_glassfish_v3) that shows the [session state preservation across redeployments](http://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/retain_session_data_during_redeployment) in GlassFish v3. Combined with the "deploy-on-save" feature (vs build and redeploy) offered by the GFv3 IDE plugins for NetBeans or Eclipse, Java EE development is very productive (even if GlassFish is not the fastest to start but well, you don't have to start it that often).

I was a big fan of Jetty but I must say that I just love these two features and consider them as direct answers to your concerns.

Comment: I will take a look at it but in my experience working a lot with V2 and a little with v3, it has to be restarted numerous times because of permgen issues. So, that would render any benefit useless in my opinion. But, I will give this a shot.

Comment: @Casey I don't have the same experience with GlassFish v3.

Comment: @Jevgeni Kabanov Care to explain the downvote (it must be you since you left a comment in the same minute)? It's of course your right to downvote my answer but I don't think it deserves it (there is nothing wrong with it apart from the fact that I am not promoting **your** product) and you could at least have the decency to leave a comment (and to say you are biased).

Comment: @Pascal
Fair enough -- I think it's ridiculous that GlassFish guys are promoting a feature that every other container has had for years, including Jetty and Tomcat. The fact that they were missing session serialization between redeploys before is abhorrent, and the way they keep pounding it as if it's something groundbreaking is pure FUD. Jetty is an awesome container, from the ground up. I vote for it and against GFv3.

Comment: @Jevgeni 1. The Jetty plugin in Eclipse is far from perfect 2. Jetty 7 is currently an horrible mess 3. Tomcat, Jetty are not Java EE servers (as stated in the title of the question) 4. For Java EE development, GFv3 is great (and I have some practical experience in that field) 5. I'm not even mentioning the case of Java EE 6.

Comment: Considering the original poster mentioned Tomcat I don't think there's any reason to exclude Jetty. As for the rest, you have your opinion, I have mine.